# Working with Angular-13 using models . can model.ts file have images as a property?

Tags: javascript, angular

Can a .model.ts file have a class with a property as an image.
and later use it using string interpolation? or is there a better way to deal with this? string interpolation ( BEGINNER ANGULAR TRYING OUT THINGS!!)

Eg:-

> **Products. model.ts**

```
 export class Products {
 name : string;
 description: string;
 price : number;
 **image  : ??**

constructor(name:string,description:string,price:number,**image:??**){
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
}
```

}

> **Product. component.ts**

```
productsList: Products[]=[
    new Products('IphoneX','this is an IphonX product',800),
    new Products('IphoneXL','this is an IphonXl product',900),
    new Products('IphoneXmini','this is an IphonXmini product',1200),
    new Products('IphoneXpromax','this is an IphonXpromax product',1340),
  ]
```

> **product.component.html**

```
<div class="card__container" *ngFor="let product of productsList">
    <mat-card>
        <div class="product" >
            <div class="product__img" >
                {{ product.img }}
            </div>
            <div class="product__details">
                <h1>{{ product.name}}</h1>
                <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
                <h3>{{ product.price | currency }}</h3>
                <button (click)="addtoCart(product)"><mat-icon>add_shopping_cart</mat-icon>Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: What would you expect this : <div class="product__img" >
                {{ product.img }}
            </div> to do.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to do:

```
image: 'some_image_name.png'
```

(or for class: `image: string`)

then have that image in assets folder (for example in assets/images), so that you can reference it from the template as:

```
<div class="product__img" >
    <img [src]="'/assets/images/' + product.img" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it Worked thanks for the explanation . To know this method , do I need to know js better or angular? Because I really didn't have any thoughts on how to do this .

Comment: It's actually a bit hard to separate the two, since Angular is just a framework and relies on JS and Typescript. In this particular case it's mostly JS, but your best bet is to go through some in-depth tutorials with good theorethical explanations - not just pure code - and then start making something from ypur ideas and from the scratch. There are lots of suggestions for first projects in Angular, so ylu can browse those too.

Comment: Ok thank you for the advice and solutions 